# Toggle checkboxes on PHP table

Tags: javascript, php, html, checkbox

I have a table with a checkbox in the table header, which will be used to toggle all the checkboxes below it. I've add a JavaScript function to the checkbox in the header, but so far it only selects the top checkbox (one checkbox) instead of all of them. Any suggestions or advice on what I've done wrong or what to research?

HTML table header code:

```
<thead>
  <tr>
    <th><center><input type="checkbox" value="" id="cbgroup1_master" onchange="togglecheckboxes(this,'cbgroup1')"></center></th>
    <th>Sender</th>
    <th>Receiver</th>
    <th>Subject</th>
    <th>Date</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
```

PHP table code:

```
$table .= '
          <tr>
            <td><center><input type="checkbox" id="cb1_1" class="cbgroup1"></center></td>
            <td><a href="pm_message.php?u='.$log_username.'&pmid='.$pmid.'" onclick="markRead(\''.$pmid.'\',\''.$sender.'\')">'.$sender.'</a></td>
            <td>'.$receiver.'</td>
            <td>'.$subject.'</td>
            <td>'.$time.'</td>
          </tr>';
```

Javascript code:

```
function togglecheckboxes(master,cn){
    var cbarray = document.getElementsByClassName(cn);
    for(var i = 0; i < cbarray.length; i++){
        var cb = document.getElementById(cbarray[i].id);
        cb.checked = master.checked;
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the javascript.

Comment: @PhiterFernandes oh my goodness! I forgot! I just updated the question with the js code. Thanks for reminding me!!

Comment: Do you feel comfortable by using jQuery? It's way easier to achieve what you want.

Comment: I have a little bit of experience using it (I've played with a few tutorials), but I'm not afraid to get my hands dirty. @PhiterFernandes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see 2 issues with you code.

**(Probably) using the same id for multiple DOM elements**

Your PHP code suggests that you are probably using a loop to create the checkboxes but you are using the same id for all of them "cb1_1".
Same as **@atul** here.

**Improperly selecting your checkbox elements**
Since you are using the same id for all inputs, 
`var cb = document.getElementById(cbarray[i].id);`always returns the same element. A way to solve it is to use the solution provided by **@atul**

Another way is to rewrite your javascript as follows :

```
function togglecheckboxes(master,cn){
    var cbarray = document.getElementsByClassName(cn);
    for(var i = 0; i < cbarray.length; i++){
        var cb = cbarray[i];
        cb.checked = master.checked;
    }
}
```

Your cbarray is already your checkboxes array, so it is redundant (aka useless) to call `document.getElementById(cbarray[i].id)` to get the element when you already have it with `cbarray[i]`.

Comment: Thank you so much and also to Atul. I really should have considered the table id being selected. Thank you for bringing things to my attention. Everything works now! Great learning experience!!

Comment: @Millica Glad to have been of service. Good luck on your programming journey !

Answer (score 2):

The problem is you setting the same ID (**cb1_1**) to all the checkboxes (which is invalid in HTML) Id should be unique in the page. Thus, it only select the first found checkbox and discard the rest. To resolve this give unique ids to checkboxes.

```
$table .= '
          <tr>
            <td><center><input type="checkbox" id="cb1_'.$pmid.'" class="cbgroup1"></center></td>
            <td><a href="pm_message.php?u='.$log_username.'&pmid='.$pmid.'" onclick="markRead(\''.$pmid.'\',\''.$sender.'\')">'.$sender.'</a></td>
            <td>'.$receiver.'</td>
            <td>'.$subject.'</td>
            <td>'.$time.'</td>
          </tr>';
```

Note: I just use the $pmid just as an example you should use appropriate value as per your scenario